# java java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪D:\qr.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Tags: java, ioexception

[image]

when i run this code it gets me " java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪‪D:\qr.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)" error

here is my code

```
 try {
        String kk = "fsdfsfs";
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(kk).to(ImageType.JPG).stream();
        File f = new File("‪‪D:\\qr.jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(out.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like there can't be magic in this question... do you have that "D:" drive and does your user have permission to write to it? Also, did you type the path by hand, or was it copied/pasted? Sometimes pasted stuff is in funny encoding...

Comment: Do you have a D:\ drive? Do you have a file `qr.jpg` available at the path you mentioned here? Does your user have permission to access the drive?

Comment: yes i have permission and that path is exists

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something funny is going on there. My advice will be to check if your program thinks the file is there and that it can write to it. Try the following and let me know what comes up:

```
try {
            String kk = "fsdfsfs";
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(kk).to(ImageType.JPG).stream();
            File f = new File("‪‪D:\\qr.jpg");
            if(f.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File exists");
            }else {
                f.createNewFile(); // if the file does not exist, create it
                System.out.println("Created non-existing file");
            }
            if(f.canWrite()) {
                System.out.println("File can be written to");
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(out.toByteArray());
            fos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Could you elaborate on the error?